# Objective-C to Swift Bitwise XOR equal Operator ^=

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have got this kind of code in Objective-C, and I want to convert to Swift

```
+ (BOOL)isLocationOutOfChina:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)location {
  BOOL oddFlag = NO;
  oddFlag ^= (a.x +
                  (c.y - a.y) /
                  (b.y - a.y) *
                  (b.x - a.x) <
                  point.x);
  return !oddFlag;
}
```

I have no idea of how to deal with Bitwise XOR equal Operator to swift `^=`

I have got an error for this convert:

`Binary operator ^= cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands`

Comment: Did you try to use `^=` in Swift? Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: Please see [Operator Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/operator_declarations)

Comment: @rmaddy I got a error: Binary operator `^=` cannot be applied to two 'Bool' operands

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. Sorry, it only applies to `Int` and related integer types.

Comment: So, Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: `!=` is XOR for booleans.  It doesn't assign like `^=` does, but that's an easy fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, the `^` operator (and hence, the `^=` operator) only works with integer data types (such as `Int`). It doesn't work with `Bool`.

But note that your use of `^=` in your Objective-C code is pointless. You always start with `NO` and then XOR that with either `YES` or `NO`. The result will be always be the value of the right-hand side. In other words `NO ^ X` will always be `X`. So simply do:

```
BOOL oddFlag = (a.x + ...);
```

in Objective-C. Then the Swift translation is simple.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Actually, I meant `NO ^ X` will always be `X`.